# Lawn mower project

Tags: wiring

I'm trying to figure out how to make a remote control lawn mower, and I'm stuck questioning one critical part

I'm in the process of buying 2 wheelchair motors that accept both 12 and 24volts which are 60 and 120 rpms which will be wired into a motor controller that also powers a receiver for the transmitter

The question I have is the motor controller, does it have to be a dual motor controller or can I pass with just a general motor controller capable of handling 12volts and can a 12volt car battery be ran to the motor controller or would it need to be regulated down to a lower voltage, I've seen videos on people using the sabre tooth dual motor controller, I'm just wondering why their all limited to one controller

Answer (score 1):

I think you're asking why the Sabertooth motor controllers are popular?

They are very good motor controllers with good manuals. They have an excellent support department.

Another good company that produces similar motor controllers is "RobotClaw."